# How to connect Droplet with PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, digital-ocean, droplet

I recently had an idea about PhpStorm and I need to use it to open project already uploaded on Droplet on Digital ocean.

I have found [this tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/create-new-project-add-remote-server.html?origin=old_help), followed it but still got failed connection. I'm using a user name and password to login to Droplet console on Digital Ocean.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: The problem seems to be very specific to PhpStorm + DigitalOcean config. I'd suggest contacting PhpStorm support via Help | Contact Support to share the details of your connection privately. If that's not an option - please attach all the available details about the problem. E.g. a connection error message & a screenshot of your config

Answer (score 1):

I can found That.. if Droplet Created using SSH it must connect with SFTP in PHPStorm Instead FTP.